# alternative to exec sql to avoid sql injection is SP_EXECUTESQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-injection

i have to connect to an existing stored procedure which saves a line of text in the database.
now i've seen the sp and it is a concatenated string (in which my text is placed) and the it is executed with `exec(@sql)`.

Because the text is coming from a public website, i have to make sure no sql injection is possible.

The database guy had not heard of sql injection, so he doesn't know what to do, but as i don't want to expose the risk from my aplication, i would like to know what can be done to prevent the sql injection. I am however more programmer than sql guy.

Now i've found the `'SP_EXECUTESQL(@SQL)'` stored procedure, will that help prevent sql injection, or is it still possible to make malicious calls?

thanks in advance for helping me.

Comment: Any chance of showing us the SQL statement (sanitised for public consumption of course)? If you are already using parameters, then you are probably safe.

Comment: it turned out the sql guy could easily replace the exec(@sql) by a normal stored proc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the MSDN documentation for `SP_EXECUTESQL(@SQL)` here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx.

It warns that

> Run time-compiled Transact-SQL
>   statements can expose applications to
>   malicious attacks, such as SQL
>   injection.

Also have a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175170.aspx

I would strongly advise against trusting ANY input from ANY user!

Can you change the query to be parameterised in some way?

Comment: yeah, i've read the article, but it also says 'The Transact-SQL statement or batch can contain embedded parameters'. I thought the usage of parameters would help against the sql injection?

Comment: Yes, using parameters protects against SQL injection. `SP_EXECUTESQL()` is suppsoed to run more efficiently than plain old `EXEC`, but has the same security concerns.

Comment: Ha ha... the worst thing is that the MSDN tutorials use this technique hahaha... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb497936.aspx

Comment: I wonder why .Net Entity Framework uses it then, there must be some benefit